# Join tables, sum over fields in one, seperate by date and field of other

Tags: sql, oracle

I am joining two tables. Then I am summing over two columns in one table for two different date periods.

However what I also wish to do is separate the date categories further into two sets of fields defined by a WHERE condition on a different field of one of the tables.

However I cannot get this result to work, I am getting ORA-00936: missing expression.

This is most likely a syntax error, however I have not been able to find an example by multiple dates and conditions as I am trying to, so I cannot find an example of how to write this.

My Code:

```
select SOME_CATEGORY_1, SOME_CATEGORY_2,
                WHERE (SOME_CATEGORY_3 = 'Value A', 
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(52*7) and SYSDATE then ms.cash_sales else 0 end) A_TY_CashSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(52*7) and SYSDATE then ms.unit_sales else 0 end) A_TY_UnitSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(104*7) and SYSDATE-(53*7) then ms.cash_sales else 0 end) A_LY_CashSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(104*7) and SYSDATE-(53*7) then ms.unit_sales else 0 end) A_LY_UnitSales
                ),
                WHERE (SOME_CATEGORY_3 = 'Value B', 
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(52*7) and SYSDATE then ms.cash_sales else 0 end) B_TY_CashSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(52*7) and SYSDATE then ms.unit_sales else 0 end) B_TY_UnitSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(104*7) and SYSDATE-(53*7) then ms.cash_sales else 0 end) B_LY_CashSales,
                sum(case when oc.week_start_date between SYSDATE-(104*7) and SYSDATE-(53*7) then ms.unit_sales else 0 end) B_LY_UnitSales
                )           
from MY_TABLE mt
join MY_OTHER_TABLE mot on mot.mykey = mt.mykey
join calendar_table ct on ct.week_id = ms.week_id
group by SOME_CATEGORY_1, SOME_CATEGORY_2
order by 1,2,3 desc
```

The result can be accomplished using two separate selects but if possible I'd like to have a single query that shows this years and last years sums for the two cases in a single query.

How can I accomplish this?

For reference this query is being applied to an Oracle database.

Comment: Can you post the create and insert statements as a sample data for test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another clause to the `case` statement to restrict by `some_category_3` e.g.

```
select some_category_1
     , some_category_2
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value a'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(52*7) and sysdate
               then ms.cash_sales
             else 0
           end) a_ty_cashsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value a'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(52*7) and sysdate
               then ms.unit_sales
             else 0
           end) a_ty_unitsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value a'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(104*7) and sysdate-(53*7)
               then ms.cash_sales
             else 0
           end) a_ly_cashsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value a'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(104*7) and sysdate-(53*7)
               then ms.unit_sales
             else 0
           end) a_ly_unitsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value b'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(52*7) and sysdate
               then ms.cash_sales
             else 0
           end) b_ty_cashsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value b'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(52*7) and sysdate
               then ms.unit_sales
             else 0
           end) b_ty_unitsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value b'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(104*7) and sysdate-(53*7)
               then ms.cash_sales
             else 0
           end) b_ly_cashsales
     , sum(case
             when     some_category_3 = 'value b'
                  and oc.week_start_date between sysdate-(104*7) and sysdate-(53*7)
               then ms.unit_sales
             else 0
           end) b_ly_unitsales
from my_table mt
     join my_other_table mot
       on mot.mykey = mt.mykey
     join calendar_table ct
       on ct.week_id = ms.week_id
group by some_category_1
       , some_category_2
order by some_category_1
       , some_category_2
```

Comment: It takes so much time and effort to reverse engineer the logic without a test case :-(